# Explicit time dependence of the Lagrangian and Energy Conservation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, symmetry, noethers-theorem

*Why is energy (or in more general terms,the Hamiltonian) not conserved when the Lagrangian has an explicit time dependence?*

I know that we can derive the identity:

> $\frac{d \mathcal{H}}{d t} = - {\partial \mathcal{L}\over \partial t}$

but is there a more ***physical and intuitive explanation for the conservation?***

Answer (score 12):

I) If a system (and hence the Lagrangian) depends explicitly on time, it can often be physically interpreted as that the system is not an [isolated system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_system). In other words, that it interacts with the environment, and hence there is no reason that the energy of the system should be conserved.

*Example:* A non-relativistic 1D point particle with Lagrangian 
$$\tag{1} L~=~\frac{1}{2}m \dot{q}^2 -V(q,t),$$ 
where the potential

$$\tag{2} V(q,t)~=~V_0(t) - F(t) q +\frac{1}{2}k(t)q^2$$

is quadratic in $q$ and the three coefficients $V_0(t)$, $- F(t)$ and $k(t)$ depend explicitly on time. We may interpret:

1. $V_0(t)$ as a fluctuating (choice of) zero-point energy. This is a total derivative term in the Lagrangian, and does not affect the equations of motion.
2. $F(t)$ as an external force.
3. $k(t)$ as a changing spring constant.

II) On the other hand, if the Lagrangian does not depend explicitly on time, so that time translation is a symmetry of the Lagrangian, then [Noether's (first) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) yields that the corresponding Noether charge (=the energy) is conserved.

Answer (score 2):

The time dependent hamiltonian also implies, that the volume element in the phase space is not conserved under time evolution.